# How does eclipse know what OSGi bundles there are that can be depended on?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Given is a simple setup of two "Plug-in Projects" created with the "Hello RCP" template.

When navigating to one project's manifest and opening the "Plug-in Selection" dialog on the dependencies tab by clicking "Add...", a list is shown of plug-ins which can be depended on from the project.

From my understanding, this list contains all the plug-ins from the current target platform and the plug-ins available in my workspace. My question is about the latter. Where are these bundles located? I only see .class files in the bin directory of the projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual jar files of the bundles are not located anywhere - the bundles will get created and resolved automatically by Eclipse once you run the OSGI project. If you want to use these bundles outside Eclipse, you will first need to export them. The location of the bundles while the project is run will be the corresponding project folders in the workspace.

Also any additional resources like "plugin.xml" or "manifest.mf" are not included in the binary folder of the project but instead listed under the "build" section of the manifest file.

Comment: "The location of the bundles while the project is run will be the corresponding project folders in the workspace."

So if I understand correctly, the jar's do get built when running from eclipse? Could you be more specific on the location? I can't seem to locate them.

Comment: No jars get built. Instead the bundles are the project folders - similar to external OSGI bundles that are not located  in jar files but instead in folders.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question.

Plug-ins in the workspace are projects which have a `Bundle-SymbolicName` in the `MANIFEST.MF`, normally these will have been created by the `File > New > Project > Plug-in Project` wizard.

Edit:

Plug-ins can be run directly from the project without being packaged in to a JAR. Generally this is not a problem but it can lead to problems with the path of resources working during testing but failing when the plug-in is put in a jar.

Comment: My apologies for my somewhat vague question. What I really want to know is the following: when I run one of the projects, where does eclipse put my bundles? (The .jar that contains a manifest) Or is this bundle not created at all?